# How to run a PHP file from other PHP file?

Tags: php, html, containers

I have a PHP file that is properly working on its own but I need it to run on a certain part of my homepage called file.php.

I want myfile.php run inside file.php, I properly div the container of where I need it and tried the `<?php include("myfile.php"); ?>` it works, but I want its auto size.

Let's say myfile.php have table with width size is 900px but when I open file.php and table size inside myfile.php become wane. Size become below 900px. How to make that still 900px that table inside myfile.php where run inside file.php with div container?

Comment: You're talking of... an `include`? ...`iframe`? ...`div` style `overlay`?

Comment: @Welly: `<` signs are interpreted as part of the markup. You might want to escape them or your line of code between backticks. Else part of your question is not visible.

Comment: please show your code

Answer (score 1):

You can use php "include"

```
<div id="container">
<?php include("myfile.php"); ?>
</div>
```

By the way, what you want to do with the size, I believe you will need of CSS to do this, not php.

Maybe this way

myfile.php

```
<table style="width:900px">
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**in file.php**

`include "path/to/myfile.php"`;

Answer (score 0):

This code index3.php with div

```
<!DOCTYPE html
   PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>JS Change Class</title>
<script language="JavaScript" src="js/adspreview.js"type="text/javascript" xml:space="preserve"></script>

<div id="container">
        <td><?php include("test.php"); ?>
</div>
</html>
```

and here code that i want to run inside index3.php

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#0000FF" colspan="2">
        <p align="center"><font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial"><b>Test</b></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Please try it, i confusing about this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First:
index3.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html
   PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>JS Change Class</title>
<script language="JavaScript" src="js/adspreview.js"type="text/javascript" xml:space="preserve"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
        <?php include("test.php"); ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Second:
teste.php

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#0000FF" colspan="2">
        <p align="center"><font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial"><b>Test</b></font>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CTRL+C + CTRL+V ^^